# Tengo este código y se que es para que no te dejen copiar y pegar en un input, alguien me lo podría explicar. Estoy usando js

Tags: javascript

```
$(document.body).on('paste', '.solo_numeros', function(event) {
        var cp = event.originalEvent.clipboardData;
        var valor = cp.getData('text/plain');
        var valorSoloNumeros = valor.replace(/[^\d\.]/g,"");
        if( valorSoloNumeros.length > 0 && !isNaN(valorSoloNumeros)){
        cp.setData('text/plain', valorSoloNumeros);
        return true
        }else{
        cp.setData('text/plain', '');
        return false;
        }
        });
```